# xamarin form - get text box value in grid

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

I have programmatically generate a grid which contain label and textbox. The code show as below

```cs
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "ID", BackgroundColor = Color.Black, IsVisible = false, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)), }, 0, 1, 0, 1);
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Desc", BackgroundColor = Color.Black, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)), }, 1, 2, 0, 1);
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Qty", BackgroundColor = Color.Black, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)), }, 2, 3, 0, 1);
grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = "Receive Qty", BackgroundColor = Color.Black, FontAttributes = FontAttributes.Bold, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Small, typeof(Label)), }, 4, 6, 0, 1);

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    sID = e.Result[i].ID.ToString();
    sQty = e.Result[i].Qty.ToString();
    sDesc = e.Result[i].DESC1.ToString();
    if(e.Result[i].ReceivedQty.ToString() == "0" )
    {
        sReceivedQty = sQty;
    }
    else
    {
        sReceivedQty = e.Result[i].ReceivedQty.ToString();
    }

    grid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition { Height = new GridLength(1, GridUnitType.Auto) });
    grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = sID, IsVisible = false, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize =  
        Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) }, 0, 1, i + 1, i + 2);
    grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = sDesc, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = 
        Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) }, 1 2, i + 1, i + 2);
    grid.Children.Add(new Label { Text = sQty, BackgroundColor = Color.Gray, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = 
        Device.GetNamedSize(NamedSize.Micro, typeof(Label)) }, 2, 3, i + 1, i + 2);
    grid.Children.Add(new Entry { Text = sReceivedQty, TextColor = Color.White, FontSize = 10 }, 3, 4, i + 1, i + 2);
}
```

I wish to get the value in the textbox for each rows? Please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can't query a `Grid` to get the element at row `X`, but you can query the element in the `Grid` and ask them their position.

```cs
//get the element at position r, c
var view = grid.Children.FirstOrDefault(v => Grid.GetRow(v) == r && Grid.GetColumn(v) == c);
var label = view as Label;
if (label != null) {
    //label.Text is the string you're looking for
}
```

Comment: How I can know the position r and c since I do not know the row index. I has another problem i face. I wish to update the data user enter in the textbox back to the database.  I got no idea how I can know the data in the textbox is belong to which ID.  Do you has any idea how I can confirm the ID is belong to the text box in same row?

Answer (score 0):

```
int index=8;
string y  = ((Label)gridName.Children.ElementAt(index)).Text;
```

This will bring the text of the label which is the 8th View in the grid.